# What does a eigenvalue equal to 0 represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The only relation I can think of is that the determinant of corresponding matrix A is 0 so A is not invertible. Could anyone suggest any other properties related to eigenspace,  orthogonal completements and projection?

Comment: The eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $0$ form the kernel of $A$.